# Game maker studio2 oшибка при создании apk. No licence for android sdk

Tags: android-sdk

gms2 просит лицензию на android sdk (отсутствует папка licenses/)

Copying C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.1.0.136/android/runner\ProjectFiles\src\main\res\values\strings.xml to C:\Users\Sash\AppData\Roaming\GameMakerStudio2\Cache\GMS2CACHE\YoYo Dunge_236E9296_38E7D0FE\Android\default\com.company.game\src\main\res\values\strings.xml... 
Copying C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.1.0.136/android/runner\ProjectFiles\src\main\res\xml\preferences.xml to C:\Users\Sash\AppData\Roaming\GameMakerStudio2\Cache\GMS2CACHE\YoYo Dunge_236E9296_38E7D0FE\Android\default\com.company.game\src\main\res\xml\preferences.xml... 
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "subst Z: "C:\Users\Sash\AppData\Roaming\GameMakerStudio2\Cache\GMS2CACHE\YoYo Dunge_236E9296_38E7D0FE\Android\default" && Z: && cd \com.company.game && "C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.1.0.136/android/runner\gradle\gradlew" build assembleRelease " 
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong: 
  A problem occurred configuring project ':com.company.game'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components: 
  >   [Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1]. 
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager. 
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.h...
- Try: 
  Run with —stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with —info or —debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 36.717 secs

C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe DONE (1) 
C:\Windows\system32\subst.exe /d Z:

C:\Windows\system32\subst.exe DONE (0) 
System.Exception: Build Failed 
в  . . (Dictionary`2  , String  , String  , Boolean  ) 
в Igor.AndroidBuilder.Package()Igor complete.

квадратики это форум не понял копи паст

в инете нашел решение для линукса, для виндовса не нашел
Установил visual studio и sdk там нет, поставил andriod studio и sdk тоже нет. Третий день расcматриваю данный вопрос, и не могу сделать apk файл

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/index.html. Там есть ссылка на скачивание SDK.

Answer (score 0):

короче решение

visual studio при установке sdk и java не прописал их в систему.
поэтому либо руками прописываем либо удаляем visual и ставим оригинал android studio, java